# React component package after installation gives error: Could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, rollup

I'm working on React component library. I'm using TypeScript. For bulding I'm using rollup.

The package is on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspackagepiotrek?activeTab=code

After installation in other project I got error:

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jspackagepiotrek'. '/home/piotr/sandbox/piece-of-code/node_modules/jspackagepiotrek/dist/esm/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I probably messed with tsconfig or rollup config, but I have no idea how to fix it.